# Unusual syntax for arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, syntax

I'm doing a school assignment that forces us to use a fixed implementation of the Main class. Inside of the implementation there is a syntax for the declaration of an array (at least it seems like it).

Bank is a class for a Bank object.

```
Bank.BANKS = new Bank[5];
```

I have never seen this syntax before and have been looking all over for what it's supposed to mean. My vague understanding of it is that it creates an array (size 5) of Bank objects, but I am not sure about the `Bank.BANKS` part.

Comment: If `Bank` is a class, then `BANKS` is a static field in it. Probably declared as `static Bank[] BANKS`

Comment: Maybe `static Bank[] BANKS;`

Comment: @ernest_k I think I kind of get it!! I have to sit on it for awhile. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It *should* be marked both `static` and `final`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bank` is the name of the class, and `BANKS` is a static data member. In other words, if you look at the class declaration, you'll probably see something like this:

```
public class Bank {
    public static Bank[] BANKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

BANKS is a static variable of class Bank.
It is a placeholder to store an array of five `Bank` objects.

Your Bank class might look like this:

```
public class Bank {
  ....
  public static Bank[] BANKS;
  ....
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bank.BANKS` is a static variable. It is as same as `Bank[] Banks = new Bank[5]`

```
public class Bank {

    public static Bank[] BANKS;

    public Bank() {
        Bank.BANKS = new Bank[5];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bank{

    static Bank[] BANKS;
  public static void main(String...arg){
       Bank.BANKS = new Bank[5];
       System.out.println(Bank.BANKS.length);


  }
}
```